# OpenGL + Kinect SDK - how to get depth value from a single pixel?

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, kinect

We are currently tracking an object in a window using a Kinect, and now we need to get the 3D instead of "2D" coordinates. Basically, we need the depth value obtained by `LockedRect.pBits` at a single point.

Our current code returns arbitrary 0's and the like, but here it is:

```
void getDepthData(GLubyte* dest) {


    NUI_IMAGE_FRAME imageFrame;
    NUI_LOCKED_RECT LockedRect;
    if (sensor->NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame(depthStream, 0, &imageFrame) < 0) return;
    INuiFrameTexture* texture = imageFrame.pFrameTexture;
    texture->LockRect(0, &LockedRect, NULL, 0);
    if (LockedRect.Pitch != 0) {
            const USHORT* curr = (const USHORT*)LockedRect.pBits;
            cout << curr;
            const USHORT* dataEnd = curr + (width*height);

            while (curr < dataEnd) {
                    // Get depth in millimeters
                    USHORT depth = NuiDepthPixelToDepth(*curr++);

                    // Draw a grayscale image of the depth:
                    // B,G,R are all set to depth%256, alpha set to 1.
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
                            *dest++ = (BYTE)depth % 256;
                    *dest++ = 0xff;
            }

    }
    texture->UnlockRect(0);
    sensor->NuiImageStreamReleaseFrame(depthStream, &imageFrame);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found a solution! To anyone wondering this same thing; pBits is the minimum value in USHORT format, and you want to find the x'th pixel after it. Picturing it in a matrix, you want to find the depth eg. 2 rows down and 3 columns right of pBits in a 5*4 matrix, giving you `pBits + 2 * width + 3` = the 13th place after pBits (visualizing it on paper helps this).

```
void getDepthData(RotatedRect trackBox, GLubyte* dest) {

NUI_IMAGE_FRAME imageFrame;
NUI_LOCKED_RECT LockedRect;
if (sensor->NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame(depthStream, 0, &imageFrame) < 0) return;
INuiFrameTexture* texture = imageFrame.pFrameTexture;
texture->LockRect(0, &LockedRect, NULL, 0);
if (LockedRect.Pitch != 0) {
    USHORT* curr = (USHORT*)(LockedRect.pBits);
    curr = curr + (USHORT)trackBox.center.y * width + (USHORT)trackBox.center.x;

        // Get depth in millimeters
        USHORT depth = NuiDepthPixelToDepth(*curr);

        cout << depth << "\n";

}
texture->UnlockRect(0);
sensor->NuiImageStreamReleaseFrame(depthStream, &imageFrame);
```

except ours does secrifice pretty code for `1*width+1` difference which isn't an issue at 40+ cm distance.